# Mystery? Azure DaaS Webjob

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-webjobs

This week I have noticed a continuous webjob on my teams azure portal.

[image]No one on the team says they have deployed it, or are familiar with it. I found this blog:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/blog/daas/

Referring something potentially related, but some of the links on this page seem to be dead. One of them redirects you to check the Azure 'Diagnose and solve problems' blade. It looks like this has had its UI revamped, though I had never really needed to use this feature much so I am not accustomed to all its previous/new? features.

In here I found some diagnostic tools that seem useful and Azure App Service 'Auto Healing'. Nothing I have found seems to rely on this webjob and 'DaaS' doesn't exist on for any of our other App Services in the Azure Portal.

Can I disable or delete this? I don't feel great about having a continuous webjob running, that no one on our team knows what it is doing, or seem to need for any reason.

Do we lose these ?new? features in the Diagnostic blade? The features seem to be available for the App Services without the webapp present for them.

Its Logs are attached as follows:

```
[11/02/2018 17:11:16 > 500837: SYS INFO] Status changed to Starting
[11/02/2018 17:11:16 > 500837: SYS INFO] WebJob singleton setting is False
[11/02/2018 17:11:16 > 500837: SYS INFO] Run script 'DaaSRunner.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[11/02/2018 17:11:16 > 500837: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[11/02/2018 18:11:16 > 500837: SYS INFO] WebJob is still running
[11/03/2018 06:11:18 > 500837: SYS INFO] WebJob is still running
[11/03/2018 09:47:19 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] Status changed to Starting
[11/03/2018 09:47:20 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] WebJob singleton setting is False
[11/03/2018 09:47:22 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] Run script 'DaaSRunner.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[11/03/2018 09:47:23 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[11/03/2018 09:48:52 > 500837: SYS INFO] WebJob is stopping due to website shutting down
[11/03/2018 09:48:52 > 500837: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopping
[11/03/2018 09:48:58 > 500837: ERR ] Thread was being aborted.
[11/03/2018 09:48:58 > 500837: SYS INFO] WebJob process was aborted
[11/03/2018 09:48:58 > 500837: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopped
[11/03/2018 09:49:59 > 88a4cd: INFO] Deleting expired heartbeat from instance RD0004FF9C15A8. It last beat at 11/3/2018 9:49:55 AM while the current time is 11/3/2018 9:49:59 AM
[11/03/2018 10:47:20 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] WebJob is still running
[11/03/2018 22:47:22 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] WebJob is still running
[11/04/2018 02:47:33 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] WebJob is stopping due to website shutting down
[11/04/2018 02:47:33 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopping
[11/04/2018 02:47:38 > 88a4cd: ERR ] Thread was being aborted.
[11/04/2018 02:47:38 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] WebJob process was aborted
[11/04/2018 02:47:38 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopped
[11/04/2018 02:47:54 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] Status changed to Starting
[11/04/2018 02:47:54 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] WebJob singleton setting is False
[11/04/2018 02:47:54 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] Run script 'DaaSRunner.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[11/04/2018 02:47:54 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[11/04/2018 03:47:54 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] WebJob is still running
[11/04/2018 15:47:56 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] WebJob is still running
[11/05/2018 03:47:57 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] WebJob is still running
[11/05/2018 15:47:59 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] WebJob is still running
[11/06/2018 03:48:01 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] WebJob is still running
[11/06/2018 15:48:03 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] WebJob is still running
[11/07/2018 03:48:04 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] WebJob is still running
[11/07/2018 15:48:06 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] WebJob is still running
[11/08/2018 03:48:08 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] WebJob is still running
[11/08/2018 15:48:10 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] WebJob is still running
[11/09/2018 02:03:23 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] WebJob is stopping due to website shutting down
[11/09/2018 02:03:23 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopping
[11/09/2018 02:03:35 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] Status changed to Starting
[11/09/2018 02:03:35 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] WebJob singleton setting is False
[11/09/2018 02:03:35 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] Run script 'DaaSRunner.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[11/09/2018 02:03:35 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[11/09/2018 02:03:44 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] Detected WebJob file/s were updated, refreshing WebJob
[11/09/2018 02:03:44 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopping
[11/09/2018 02:03:49 > 88a4cd: ERR ] Thread was being aborted.
[11/09/2018 02:03:49 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] WebJob process was aborted
[11/09/2018 02:03:49 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopped
[11/09/2018 02:03:49 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] Status changed to Starting
[11/09/2018 02:03:49 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] Job directory change detected: Job file 'DaaS.dll' timestamp differs between source and working directories.
[11/09/2018 02:03:49 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] Run script 'DaaSRunner.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[11/09/2018 02:03:49 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[11/09/2018 03:03:49 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] WebJob is still running
[11/09/2018 03:53:32 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] Status changed to Starting
[11/09/2018 03:53:32 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] WebJob singleton setting is False
[11/09/2018 03:53:33 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] Run script 'DaaSRunner.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[11/09/2018 03:53:33 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[11/09/2018 04:53:32 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] WebJob is still running
[11/09/2018 04:56:49 > 522a7d: SYS INFO] Status changed to Starting
[11/09/2018 04:56:49 > 522a7d: SYS INFO] WebJob singleton setting is False
[11/09/2018 04:56:50 > 522a7d: SYS INFO] Run script 'DaaSRunner.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[11/09/2018 04:56:51 > 522a7d: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[11/09/2018 04:58:23 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] WebJob is stopping due to website shutting down
[11/09/2018 04:58:23 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopping
[11/09/2018 04:58:28 > 88a4cd: ERR ] Thread was being aborted.
[11/09/2018 04:58:28 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] WebJob process was aborted
[11/09/2018 04:58:28 > 88a4cd: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopped
[11/09/2018 04:59:48 > 522a7d: INFO] Deleting expired heartbeat from instance RD0004FF9C349E. It last beat at 11/9/2018 4:59:20 AM while the current time is 11/9/2018 4:59:48 AM
[11/09/2018 05:56:50 > 522a7d: SYS INFO] WebJob is still running
[11/09/2018 13:00:14 > 60c00d: SYS INFO] Status changed to Starting
[11/09/2018 13:00:14 > 60c00d: SYS INFO] WebJob singleton setting is False
[11/09/2018 13:00:15 > 60c00d: SYS INFO] Run script 'DaaSRunner.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[11/09/2018 13:00:15 > 60c00d: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[11/09/2018 13:01:01 > 522a7d: SYS INFO] WebJob is stopping due to website shutting down
[11/09/2018 13:01:01 > 522a7d: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopping
[11/09/2018 13:01:06 > 522a7d: ERR ] Thread was being aborted.
[11/09/2018 13:01:06 > 522a7d: SYS INFO] WebJob process was aborted
[11/09/2018 13:01:06 > 522a7d: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopped
[11/09/2018 13:02:41 > 60c00d: INFO] Deleting expired heartbeat from instance RD0004FF9C4287. It last beat at 11/9/2018 1:02:00 PM while the current time is 11/9/2018 1:02:41 PM
[11/09/2018 14:00:14 > 60c00d: SYS INFO] WebJob is still running
[11/10/2018 02:00:15 > 60c00d: SYS INFO] WebJob is still running
[11/10/2018 14:00:16 > 60c00d: SYS INFO] WebJob is still running
```

Which doesn't tell me a whole lot. Please let me know if this is a new feature, or I am getting ABTested, or if you think this can be disabled/removed. Thank you.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

After opening a ticket with Microsoft they told me that because I had browsed around on the 'Diagnose and Solve' blade, this webjob was created automatically to allow for the functionality expected there.

I didn't end up needing those options currently so I am safe to disable it, or delete it. It should not interfere with my application but if it is not doing anything I figure I should at least disable it.

After disabling it, I have not experienced any issues on my side, or for the users.

Answer (score 5):

I tried to go to the `DaaS` page, but the function has been **deprecated** as shown in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5zS7.png). And the page also suggested to use the "Diagnose and Solve".So I believe the `DaaS WebJob` could be removed.

Now that it works as a continuous `webjob` you can find and remove it from `Kudu`. You could access[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feJHe.png) `https：// <YourSiteName>.scm.azurewebsites.net` then choose the Tools->Zip Push Deploy->App_Data->jobs->continuous. If the "DaaS" is there, you could click **-** to delete it like the [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feJHe.png).

If you still have questions, please let me know.

Comment: Hey George. Yes I followed those links, they were what I referred to in my post. My question is, this DaaS webjob never existed before, and I don't see why I should keep it, unless it is doing something new I am unaware about. I don't think they would have created it automatically for me a couple weeks ago, if this has been deprecated for years?

Comment: I tried to use Daas but it did show me it's deprecated, and the official said it replaced by "Diagnose and Solve" so it's not necessary to keep it and remove it from "Kudu". As for your doubt about why it was created automatically, sorry i can't find the reason.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thank you for your help looking into/confirming this. Azure seems to get upgrades pretty often, and I must not be very well looped in on it. Sometimes it seems like strange things happen. Overall I've been extremely pleased with it though.

Answer (score 5):

I had a same issue, In my Web Application I have a single web job and suddenly I saw another web job named "Daas". 
So I was quite surprised and had a discussion with MS Team about the same then I found that if you have activated "Dignosis tools" for your web app then this "Daas" web job automatically created by Azure cloud. 
Basically it will monitor your current web app for any issues or threats. 
So nothing to worry about it, it won't consume your app's memory.

Comment: I also saw this and it ended up consuming all cpu (100%) even when all web jobs AND app services were shut down.

Answer (score 4):

Here is more information about DaaS and DaasRunner

- https://github.com/Azure/DaaS/wiki

It should be noted that whenever you run any Diagnostic Tools via **Diagnose and Solve Problems** blade, they collect data via the DaaS site extension and during that time they depend upon the DaasRunner webjob. This is true for tools like Memory Dump, .NET Profiler, CPU monitoring, Java Flight Recorder, Autohealing, etc.

It is possible that the DaasRunner webjob might re-appear if you browse to any Diagnostic tools in Diagnose and Solve problems blade. More details in the below article

- https://github.com/Azure/DaaS/wiki/Why-does-the-DaasRunner-webjob-keep-coming-back-%3F

> It should be noted that the DaaSRunner webjob is mostly sitting idle and doing nothing. Only when a diagnostic session (like CPU Monitoring session) or a manual data collection session (like Profiler, Memory dump, etc.) is invoked, the DaasRunner wakes up and starts collecting data required by that session so it is totally harmless to leave the DaasRunner Webjob in a running state.